# Multiplayer Tic Tac Toe with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, tic-tac-toe, socket.io

I am trying to learn Socket.io and develop a multiplayer tic tac toe game. Right now, I have developed a game that plays well when hosted locally, but I cannot seem to transmit game moves between the client(s) and the server. How can I improve my game?

Index.html (with client-side JS)

```
<body>

<h1 id="title">Let's Play a Game</h1>
<h3></h3>

<div id="gameboard">

    <canvas id = "sq1"  width="75" height="75" style="border:1px solid black" ></canvas>
    <canvas id = "sq2"  width="75" height="75" style="border:1px solid black" ></canvas>
    <canvas id = "sq3"  width="75" height="75" style="border:1px solid black" ></canvas>

    <br>

    <canvas id = "sq4"  width="75" height="75" style="border:1px    solid black" ></canvas>
    <canvas id = "sq5"  width="75" height="75" style="border:1px solid black" ></canvas>
    <canvas id = "sq6"  width="75" height="75" style="border:1px solid black" ></canvas>

    <br>

    <canvas id = "sq7"  width="75" height="75" style="border:1px solid black" ></canvas>
    <canvas id = "sq8"  width="75" height="75" style="border:1px solid black" ></canvas>
    <canvas id = "sq9"  width="75" height="75" style="border:1px solid black" ></canvas>

</div>


<button type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset">Reset</button>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
//Client-Side socket code
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

//Global Vars
var painted;
var thisSquare;
var c;
var ctx;
var toWin = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];;
var content;
var painted;
var content;
var turn;
var squareFilled;
var title = $("#title");
var canPlay;

//This contains the state of the board
var state = {
    sq1:'',
    sq2:'',
    sq3:'',
    sq4:'',
    sq5:'',
    sq6:'',
    sq7:'',
    sq8:'',
    sq9:''
}


//Prepares gameboard
$(document).ready(function(){

    squaresFilled = 0;
    turn = 0;
    painted = new Array();
    content = new Array();
    canPlay = true;

    //clear paint and content of gameboard
    for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++){
        painted[i] = false;
        content[i]='';
    }

 });

$('canvas').on("click", function(){
    //find number of canvas clicked
    var n = event.target.id.slice(-1);

   //If turn is even play X, if odd play 0
   if(canPlay){
        //Isolate context of clicked square
        thisSquare = "sq"+n;
        //Draw on canvas
        c = document.getElementById(thisSquare);
        cxt = c.getContext("2d");

        //if square isn't painted
        if(!painted[n-1]){
            turn++;
            //Pain an X on determined square
            if(turn%2===0){
                //HTML Canvas Painting X and memoizes symbol
                cxt.beginPath();
                cxt.moveTo(15,15);
                cxt.lineTo(60,60);
                cxt.moveTo(60,15);
                cxt.lineTo(15,60);
                cxt.stroke();
                cxt.closePath();
                content[n-1] = 'X';
                state[thisSquare] = 'X';
                socket.emit("clicked", {state:state})
            }else{
                //HTML Canvas Painting 0 and memoizes symbol
                cxt.beginPath();
                cxt.arc(38,38,30,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                cxt.stroke();
                cxt.closePath();
                content[n-1] = 'O';
                state[thisSquare] = 'O';
                socket.emit("clicked", {state: state})
            }
        //If clicked on used square    
        }else{
            alert("Try a different square");
        }

        painted[n-1] = true;
        //Check for winners
        checkWinners(content[n-1]);

        if(turn >= 9){
            //Game over
            $("#title").append("<h3>Game Over!</h3>");

           canPlay = false;
        }
    }
});

//Iterate through winner table and see if the appropriate symbol combination exits
function checkWinners(e){
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        threeInARow(toWin, e, i);
    }
};


//Checks if user has scored 3x in a row
function threeInARow(toWin, e, i){
    var spot1 = content[toWin[i][0]];
    var spot2 = content[toWin[i][1]];
    var spot3 = content[toWin[i][2]];

    if(spot1 == e && spot2 == e && spot3 == e){
        $("#title").append("<h3>" + e +" is the winner! </h3>");
        canPlay = false;

    } 
 };

 $("#reset").on("click", function(){
     location.reload();
 });     


</script>

</body>
```

Server-Side JS

```
var app = require('express')(); 
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//Show when player connects and disconnects
io.on('connection', function(socket){
     console.log('a user connected');
io.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
});

//Paint square when opponent makes move
socket.on("clicked", function(state){
console.log("click")
if(canPay){
    for(var square in state){
        var sq = square;
        var num = sq.slice(-1);
        var thisSq = $("#"+sq+"");
        if(!painted[n-1]){
           turn++;
            if(state[square] === "X"){
                //HTML Canvas Paints X and memoizes symbol
               c = document.getElementById(thisSq);
               cxt = c.getContext("2d");
               cxt.beginPath();
               cxt.moveTo(15,15);
               cxt.lineTo(60,60);
               cxt.moveTo(60,15);
               cxt.lineTo(15,60);
               cxt.stroke();
               cxt.closePath();
               content[n-1] = 'X';
               state[thisSquare] = 'X';

            }else if(state[square] === "O"){
                //HTML Canvas Paints O and memoizes symbol
                c = document.getElementById(thisSq);
                cxt = c.getConte
                cxt.beginPath();
                cxt.arc(38,38,30,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                cxt.stroke();
                cxt.closePath();
                content[n-1] = 'O';
                state[thisSquare] = 'O';
            }else{
               alert("Try a different square");
            } 


            painted[num-1] = true;
            //Check for winners
            checkWinners(content[num-1]);

            //If all square are taken, game over
            if(turn >= 9){
                //Game over
                $("#title").append("<h3>Game Over Fuckers!</h3>");

                canPlay = false;
               }

            }
        }
    }
 });

});
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  Unfortunately, [broken code is off-topic here.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3650/53820)  A quick glance shows that you have `if(canPay){` which should probably be `if(canPlay){`. It's also not clear to me that you start `canPlay` as `true`, but perhaps it happens somewhere that I didn't see.

Answer (score 2):

As @Brythan explained, your code is off topic as it does not do as told.

So in this answer I will only be reviewing the part that works: the HTML.

## Way too much canvas

I don't quite understand why you have a canvas for each square when you are merely writing a single character to that square.

Why don't you create a 3 by 3 `table`? That way, everything is already formatted for you and you don't have to any difficult positioning of letters or squares. For the letters, all you have to do is set the style property `text-align` to `center` to center the text.